# How can I get data outside the loop when using loop with $.get

Tags: javascript, loops, getjson

I'm very new at Javascript. I had some issue going on with my script
I had to loop through $.get and I stuck in a loop here is my code

```
a = ["{"sid":"13485"}","{"sid":"25114"}","{"sid":"45145"}"]

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=1){
       .$get('url' + "?params=" + a[i],function(data2){             
           school = data2['data']; 
        });
    }

    console.log(school);
```

When I tried to console.log(school) it keeps showing "object{}"

How can I get the data outside loop?

I would be really grateful if you can help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

you must use the callback function or something like this.

because the $.get is async function and when

```
console.log(school);
```

execute(!) the school is not evaluated yet.

you can use some things like this.

```
    a = ["{"sid":"13485"}","{"sid":"25114"}","{"sid":"45145"}"]

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=1){
       .$get('url' + "?params=" + a[i],function(data2){             
           school = data2['data']; 
           console.log(school);
        });
    }
```

or

```
a = ["{"sid":"13485"}","{"sid":"25114"}","{"sid":"45145"}"]
var  school ={};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=1){
   .$get('url' + "?params=" + a[i],function(data2){             
       school = data2['data']; 
       whenitready();
    });
}

function whenitready(){
   console.log(school);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait until all your requests are done, you need something like this:

```
var endpoints = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=1) {
  endpoints.push($.get('url' + '?params=' + a[i]));
}
$.when.apply($, endpoints).done(function () {
  // Function arguments array differs if we have one or more than one endpoint.
  // When called with one endpoint arguments is an array of three elements [data, textStatus, jqXHR].
  // When called with more than one endpoint arguments is an array of arrays [[data, textStatus, jqXHR], ...].
  // Normalize the single endpoint to the generic list one.
  var args = endpoints.length > 1 ? arguments : [arguments];
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    var data = args[i][0];
    // Do stuff here with every data received...
    school = ... 
  }

  console.log(school);
});
```